# How to see all the unlocked package version creation attempts and details in the UI

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, package, unlocked-package

I'd like to visually see the equivalent of the result of this CLI command in salesforce UI. When I go to **Setup -> Package Manager**, I only see a list of packages that I've created from within the UI.

```
sfdx force:package:version:list -v production
```

- Is it possible and if yes where can I find and see that data?
- My other question is, if my package version is successfully created, would it show up here in this list of packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible and if yes where can I find and see that data?

No.

> My other question is, if my package version is successfully created, would it show up here in this list of packages?

No. Only installed packages appear here.

Right now, I don't think there's a timeline for when, or if, Second-Generation Metadata will appear in Setup. It's not "meant" to be used that way.

The current workaround would be to install the package(s) somewhere, maybe in a Scratch Org, and then you can see the contents.